# Running python on windows command line error

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to run this code to run python on windows command line.

```
start py -m resource_server.app &> keys_server.out&
```

However, I am getting this error, how do I fix it?

```
& was unexpected at this time.
```

Comment: What are the `&`'s supposed to do?

Comment: This question doesn't actually have anything to do with programming, it's just about the command line. But... what are you *expecting* the `&` signs to *mean* in this command? What exactly do you want the command to do?

Comment: That is sh shell syntax, not windows cmd. Try it from git-bash or some other *nix shell.

Comment: I'm not too sure on the & signs either. I guess its like a process parallelism or something